# How to avoid duplication of children repositories in a parent project

Tags: gradle, repository, multi-project

I have a multi-project build with the following structure:

```
Root project 'just-another-root-project'
+--- Project ':producer'
\--- Project ':consumer'
```

---

The root `settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = 'just-another-root-project'
include 'consumer', 'producer'
```

...connects created modules.

---

The `producer.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

group 'com.github.yarbshk.jarp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.nuiton.org/release/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun:tools:1.7.0.13'
}
```

...has an external dependency (`com.sun.tools`) that is not published in Maven Central therefore I've added a link to the Nuiton repository.

---

The `consumer.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.github.yarbshk.jarp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor project(':producer')
}
```

---

The build described above is not working! To make it so I was enforced to duplicate all repositories from `producer.gradle` into `consumer.gradle`. **So the question is how to build the root project without the excessive dependency duplication?** How to do it in the right way? Thanks for any answer or hint :)

---

**UPDATE 1**:

I get the following error when try to build the project with files shown above:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':consumer:compile'.
> Could not find com.sun:tools:1.7.0.13.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/tools/1.7.0.13/tools-1.7.0.13.pom
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/tools/1.7.0.13/tools-1.7.0.13.jar
  Required by:
      project :consumer > project :producer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure repositories directly in the root project like that:

**root project build.gradle**:

```
// configure repositories for all projects
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.nuiton.org/release/'
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT* (from you comment on other response)

You can also define only `mavenCentral()` repository on root project level (it will be added to repositories for all projects) and configure `http://maven.nuiton.org/release` repository only for *producer* subproject :

*root project*

```
repositories {
    // will apply to all project
    mavenCentral()
}
```

*producer project*

```
 repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.nuiton.org/release/'
    }
    // mavenCentral inherited from root project
}
```

*consumer project*

```
// no need to re-define repositories here.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @M.Ricciuti .. i thought that solution should work as well but i got the error (please see update 1 to the question)

Comment: i created a simple project with same configuration as given in your quetion, and did not reproduce your problem. but if I change dependency type from `implementation` to `compile` in the *producer* build script, then I get exactly the same error as the one you described in **update 1** : maybe there are differences between the code in your project script and the scripts you gave in this question? by the way: which Gradle version are you using ?

Comment: So strange behaviour... In my case, it's not working for both `implementation` and `compile` therefore it needs to test more detail (create a project from scratch in the same way as you did it in spite of I have copy pasted the configuration literally). I'll make it on Monday morning and then reply you again because I don't have the computer near me now. **The current Gradle version I used is 4.6**

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in an official gradle tutorial dedicated to this:
https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/#configure_from_above

The root project can configure all projects:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter() 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @StephenFriedrich for a quick answer. i know how to configure children projects from a parent one but can i keep specific configuration in a child project (for example the `repositories` property) without modifying parent one (as shown in the `consumer.gradle` file above)?